# Is there an English equivalent for the Italian saying "It's another pair of sleeves"?

Tags: phrase-request, translation, idiom-request

In a meeting an Italian told a puzzled English audience: "It's another pair of sleeves".

It's an Italian way of saying: "it's another thing", or "this new argument is something different or off topic". The phrase could be used to remark that the new argument is something different or off topic. I don't think it can be used for pointing something unique.

In the context of the meeting it was used to note that the new argument was about a completely different thing with no connection with the previous one. The expression comes from the medieval use of interchangeable sleeves in woman dress.

There is some similar colorful way of saying this meaning ?

Comment: We have a similar saying in French ("C'est une autre paire de manches") which means some situation is much more complicated than another or simply cannot be compared to the other.

Comment: i have added some more explanation. For italian reader there is a wikipedia link explaining the idiom: https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%88_un_altro_paio_di_maniche

Comment: quick note of signification: sleeves used to come separated from the shirt's body, and you would change sleeves according to the task or the circumstances. Changing sleeves means you would be doing something different.

Comment: This saying is also used in Dutch language. We use it to indicate that somethings is **different and harder to solve.** In context: you've solved a mathematical equation. Someone asks: "Can you solve this similar equation (same catergory of equation, but more complex". Answer: "That's another pair of sleeves" to indicate it's kind of the same equation, but it's fron a different level because it's way more complex to solve.

Comment: In German, it's another pair of boots, or they are two different pairs of boots.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

In British English, you can indicate that two subjects, things or situations are completely different by saying about one of them:

> [That's another kettle of fish](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-another-a-different-kettle-of-fish)
>   That's a different kettle of fish

It can be used *verbatim*, on its own, in various circumstances. If, for example,  somebody brings up a subject that, in your opinion, is nothing to do with the current topic of conversation.

It can also be used to emphasise that the second subject is considerably more demanding than the first, for example:

> Lend you a hundred pounds? No problem: but ten thousand pounds? That's a different kettle of fish altogether!

You can also use it to make it clear that you consider two things or situations are completely different. Here are two examples:

> Practical (or everyday) intelligence seems to be a different kettle of fish from academic intelligence [Mechanisms of everyday cognition](https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=bvAH5Ck-MsoC&pg=PA205&dq=%22a%20different%20kettle%20of%20fish%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwimvIr3m7TOAhXDVRoKHXqlCO4Q6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=%22a%20different%20kettle%20of%20fish%22&f=false)
>
> When it's your own [son], that's a different kettle of fish. [A beautiful death](https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=8-iTThPf-egC&pg=PT111&dq=%22a%20different%20kettle%20of%20fish%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwin7NSynLTOAhXHtBoKHUnCDis4ChDoAQhLMAk#v=onepage&q=%22a%20different%20kettle%20of%20fish%22&f=false)

Comment: Too bad the OP hasn't given any more details yet, as the original phrase could be interpreted two ways. Yours, saying that this new topic is random and came out of nowhere, and the other one that could mean that something does not compare to something else because it is remarkable or unique. We need more context.

Comment: The phrase could be used  to remark that the new argument is something different or off topic. I don't think could be used for pointing something unique

Comment: @maborg: agreed. It is saying that two subjects, things or situations are not the same as each other: it does not imply that either is unique.

Comment: @JavaLatte _Un altro paio di maniche_ means that two things are different, but usually the second one is seen as much more complex then the first. So I'm not sure whether your answer really conveys this meaning.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano,  One of the usages is indeed when there is a difference in degree, for example the second situation is more difficult than the first.  If you asked me for advice about various repairs your car, I might say "Change the spark plugs? No problem... but replace a piston? That's a different kettle of fish altogether!". Another example: "Lend you 50 pounds? no problem. but lend you five thousand? That's a different kettle of fish!"

Comment: It's not uncommon to hear variations on this one - "a different barrel of monkeys" is common, but I've heard many fitting the pattern "a different [odd container] of [odd animal or item]". Some people also cross it over with sayings like "a different ball game" to create even weirder sayings, but that's a whole different bucket of fruitbats.

Comment: @JavaLatte +1. This really looks like a perfect English equivalent for `Un altro paio di maniche`

Comment: @anaximander; these are examples of **mixed metaphors**. The original **barrel of monkeys** one is **more fun than a barrel of monkeys**... completely different meaning.

Answer (score 39):

The first thing that came to mind was "[That's a whole new ball game](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/ball%20game)" or "That's a different ball game", but that saying is primarily used for situations and not things. As JavaLatte mentioned, this is more common in AmE than BrE. There are some variations on the phrase because "ball game" has come to mean a state of affairs, or a situation.

> Oh, you want ME to guide you down Death River instead of hiring someone else to do it. That's a whole new ball game.

If you wanted to talk about how something was completely different from something else, you might use "[a different ball of wax](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+different+ball+of+wax)". The is usually used when something might seem the same, but is actually really different. For example:

> Melissa Etheridge had already been raising two children, so she was no novice parent when her twins were born last October.

> But the new additions, she tells PEOPLE, have turned out to be "a whole different ball of wax."

<sub>The link to the People article (`http://www.people.com/people/article/0,,20058634,00.html`) that was the source of the quote above is dead.</sub>

Comment: "A whole new ballgame" originated in the 1960s, and rapidly overtook the use of "a different kettle of fish" in the United States. It is used in the UK, but it seems unlikely that it will catch up with "a different kettle of fish".  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+different+kettle+of+fish%2Ca+whole+new+ball+game&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20different%20kettle%20of%20fish%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20whole%20new%20ball%20game%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I think "a whole new ball game" has additional meaning, particularly that the new element might not so much be orthogonal to the original one, but it is, or creates a situation, of a different order of magnitude, or a much larger scope that it was originally. "Sending an unmanned probe into orbit was quite a technical feat in the 50's, but when Nasa decided on a fleet of reusable space shuttles, that was a whole new ball game"

Answer (score 33):

The first thing that pops into my mind is

> That's a horse of a different color.

Comment: I was going to say a mule of a another color but that's a different ball of wax.

Comment: I've never heard this in my life. Then again, I'm 23, maybe it's an older expression?

Comment: @ChrisCirefice You really should watch the Wizard of Oz.

Answer (score 22):

In spoken American English you have **that's a *whole* 'nother story**, with emphasis on 'whole'.  This same structure can be applied to some of the other answers here, such as "that's a whole 'nother ball game". See http://grammarist.com/usage/a-whole-nother/ .

In fact, using this structure you could probably even get away with a literal translation: "**but that's a *whole* 'nother pair of sleeves**."  So long as the emphasis was placed correctly people would totally get the meaning (and might even be tickled by the outlandish spin) even (or especially) if they'd never heard the 'pair of sleeves' idiom before.

Comment: Or "a whole 'nother can of worms", if the unrelated topic is also really complicated.

Answer (score 14):

A slightly less common variant is ["a whole nuther ball of wax"](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview?id=243022) (with the misspelled "nuther" instead of "other").  It is definitely colorful...

Comment: Looks like @ColleenV beat me to the phrase... but without the colorful misspelling of nuther.  I'll stand by my hick-oriented colorful phrasing!

Comment: The more answers, the better, especially when they're colorful ;) I didn't notice your answer when I edited mine to include it.

Comment: +1, but it should likely be "a whole nother..." Historically it was *a nother* and then it shifted to *an other* and then to *another*. As a side note, the *whole* infix is the rare non-expletive infix. (The only one I can think of off the top of my head.)

Comment: @MichaelDeardeuff I had to look up "non-expletive infix."  (The "non-expletive" part I knew - it was the "infix" part I was curious about.)  Learn something new every day...

Answer (score 8):

If I am not mistaken, the original Italian expression is *È un’altro paio di maniche* and corresponds to *C’est une autre paire de manches* in French and *Dat is een ander paar mouwen* in Dutch.

There are several ways to translate this into English, e.g.

- that’s a different kettle of fish;
- that’s a horse of a different colour.

(For some other Italian expressions, see [Italian expressions that you won’t believe exist](http://www.italianbusinesstips.com/italian-expressions-wont-believe-exist/).)

Answer (score 7):

It’s not as colorful as the idioms
with the fish, horse, wax and other balls,
but “it’s [beside the point](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/275536/26083/besides-the-point-or-beside-the-point)” is a common phrase
that means that a statement or issue
is [unimportant](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/beside-the-point) or [irrelevant](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/beside-the-point) to the topic being discussed.

Comment: If I read the original question correctly, this is the answer.  It seemed to be saying that some point was out of the context of an active argument, the others don't work for that at all.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps the idiom, "comparing apples and oranges" - two things which are fundamentally different.

Comment: Also "chalk and cheese" which redirects to "apples and oranges" on Wikipedia.

Comment: From the question: `The phrase could be used to remark that the new argument is something different or off topic. I don't think it can be used for pointing something unique.` I don't think this expression matches very well what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @ColleenV As an antipodean Queen's English speaker I'd consider "Apples & oranges" a reasonable choice here, if not the best one.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not entirely sure of the context where you'd use 'another pair of sleeves', but most of the answers seem to be about either how you'd respond to someone else deviating from the topic, or how a subject etc. might escalate.

If you find yourself changing the topic, and want to get back on topic, you might say.

> But that's another story for another day.

---

Aside, but you may be interested, there is an English idiom about clothes. People who have more than one role in a particular context say they have that 'hat' on when something they say belongs to a specific role.

> With my volunteers hat on, I definitely agree, I'd really like to see some better coffee in the break room, but with my treasurers hat on we really can't afford to upgrade the equipment.

There's no literal hat in this situation, it's purely metaphor. It's used to differentiate the motives behind different statements, and when someone is saying something to serve a particular role, as opposed to their own feelings on the matter.

Answer (score 5):

A simple way to say this is, "that's a different conversation," or "that's a different discussion."

An idiomatic English expression is, "That's a horse of a different color."

That is, the topic just introduced is unrelated to the one immediately preceding.

Answer (score 5):

Particularly if you are talking to a British person, you could simply announce:

"and now for something completely different"

Link to the ['origin'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/And_Now_for_Something_Completely_Different)

[Ngrams comparison with a whole new ball game](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=now%20for%20something%20completely%20different%2Ca%20whole%20new%20ballgame&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnow%20for%20something%20completely%20different%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20whole%20new%20ballgame%3B%2Cc0), showing both are roughly equal, despite the population of the US being much higher than that of the UK.

Comment: Certainly it has a cult following, but do you think  it could be used as comment on an off-topic subject? I would have thought it would be used as a way of introducing a change in subject.

Comment: As my Ngrams link shows, this is a heavily used phrased, on par with A whole new ball game, but obviously with variation by country for both. Your use of the term 'cult following' is odd.

And yes, you can use it as either a segue, or as commentary on a recent segue.

Comment: NGram is a powerful but blunt instrument: it tells you **how often** a word sequence is used, but not **how** it is used. You need to click on the links at the bottom of the graph and check a few instances of usage: if you find ones that match your theory, copy a couple of sentences and their links into your answer. Cult following? Hell yeah! Nerdy adolescents glued to the box for an hour every week, unable to go a whole day without saying "this parrot is dead!" or "I'm a lumberjack and I'm OK".

Comment: +100 for the link to monty pythons

Answer (score 4):

Another common way to say this is "[Neither here nor there](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/neither+here+nor+there)"

> Cliché of no consequence or meaning; irrelevant and immaterial.
>
> Whether you go to the movie or stay at home is neither here nor there.
>   Your comment—though interesting—is neither here nor there.

Comment: Your suggestion certainly fits the **off topic** idea, but not some of the other possible usages.

Answer (score 3):

**It isn't in the same ballpark** is an expression that means that two things are not of similar nature. It is often used when comparing numbers, but not exclusively.

A more colorful version that you could use comes in the form of a quote from the movie Pulp Fiction: *It is not the same ballpark, it is not the same league, it is not even the same sport*.

(Note: I have omitted a couple of, ahem, *colorful* adjectives from this quote).

Answer (score 3):

Another related idiom is "It's a whole different animal." Animal, in this case, being this definition of the word:

Animal - 6. thing:
E.g. 'A perfect job? Is there any such animal?'

So, in other words, the phrase is "It's a whole different thing."

Comment: Welcome to ELL. A good answer usually includes some examples or references, for example real sentences that contain the expression that you are suggesting. You can find these, and much more, using Google Ngram: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+whole+different+animal&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20whole%20different%20animal%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I thought this one too, as in, "that's a whole different beast".